# ReparsePoint attribute remove PowerShell

Tags: powershell, reparsepoint

Hi I have some files on network share that I need to remove ReparsePoint attribute. I have tried to set those file attributes to 'Normal' but it didn't remove 'ReparsePoint'

```
Clear-Host
$Path = "\\network\share"
Get-ChildItem  $Path -recurse -force | ForEach {
($_.Attributes = "normal") 
}
```

How I can remove 'ReparsePoint' attribute from those files?

Comment: Are you sure what you want to do? For me it seems that you trying to preform operation similar to "remove 'file' attribute from files".

Comment: I have some stube links that lost access to archive and I need to move them to other location for future reference but copy operation fails. I was told by vendor that i'll need to remove ReparsePoint attribute before I can copy those files. Above code is just example and will be changed just to find corrupted files. Just don't know how to what command I can pipe results of get-childitem to remove ReparsePoint attribute

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found tool which works on ReparsePoint.

fsutil reparsepoint delete file_name

```
Clear-Host
$Path = "\\network\share"
Get-ChildItem  $Path -recurse -force | Where-Object {($_.Length -like 1022) | ForEach {
fsutil reparsepoint delete $_ } 
}
```

Comment: So you wanted to delete reparsepoint. That's not what you asked in the first place.